# reactjs - render array separating contents from styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wrapper

I am looking at refactoring an array of data - into a set of 4 columns per row.

current react sandbox
https://rtcex.csb.app/

so lets say the contents is like this

```
let rowContents = [
    {"id": "col1Id", "type": "label", "contents": "col 1"},
    {"id": "col2Id", "type": "value", "contents": "col 2"},
    {"id": "col3Id", "type": "label", "contents": "col 3"},
    {"id": "col4Id", "type": "value", "contents": "col 4"},
    {"id": "col5Id", "type": "label", "contents": "col 5"},
    {"id": "col6Id", "type": "value", "contents": "col 6"}
];
```

and I currently have a map rendering the data like this

```
{
 rowContents.map(function(item, i){
  return (
    <Col key={i} id={item.id} className={"col-md-3 " + item.type}>{item.contents}</Col>
  );
 })
}
```

-- but this will just render all the col markup -- and I'd like to add a header/footer aspect to the render so it adds a Row wrapper - at every 4th element.

e.g. expected output

```
<Row>
    <Col id="col1Id" className="col-md-3 label">col1</Col>
    <Col id="col2Id" className="col-md-3 value">col2</Col>
    <Col id="col3Id" className="col-md-3 label">col3</Col>
    <Col id="col4Id" className="col-md-3 value">col4</Col>
<Row>
<Row>
    <Col id="col5Id" className="col-md-3 label">col5</Col>
    <Col id="col6Id" className="col-md-3 value">col6</Col>
<Row>
```

Comment: https://rtcex.csb.app/ - something like this -- but with bootstrap

Comment: if(i%4 == 0) { console.log("----new row"); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *little* helping function (using `Array#reduce`):

```js
const r = [{ foo: 1 }, { foo: 2 }, { foo: 3 }, { foo: 4 }, { foo: 5 }, { foo: 6 }];
const getData = (r, splitBy) => r.reduce((s, a) => (s[0].push(a), s[0].length === splitBy ? (s.push(s[0]), s[0] = []) : s, s), [[]]).filter((a) => a.length).reverse();

console.log(getData(r, 4));
```

And then inside render:

```
{
  getData(rowContents).map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <Row>
         {item.map((item) => 
           <Col key={i} id={item.id} className={"col-md-3 " + item.type}>
              {item.contents}
           </Col>
         )}
      </Row>
    );
  })
}
```

**However** there might be some more readable solutions for this, just wanted to make some tweaks on it.

Comment: there may be a bug with this - as the order of items is now looking incorrect -- either the children or the groupings themselves

Comment: @Rob can u gimme some example?

Comment: -- I removed the reverse in the getData thing

Comment: I think that's fixed it-- just the initial array - top to bottom - started looking out of order

Comment: @Rob Hmm, afaik reverse function had to be there, but if it works well for you without it, thats fine

Comment: I have noticed another bug -- if the array falls short of grouping --- the last element appears on top

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355657/javascript-data-grouping-and-rendering

Comment: -- something is wrong with the getData function -- I will have to use the other one below.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way would be to use a helper function to split everything and then group it.

note: the function can work with other numbers of splits, so you can change the amount of `<Cols/>` inside your `<Rows/>`

```
function spliceArrayInGroups(list, howMany) {
  var result = []
  input = list.slice(0)
  while (input[0]) {
    result.push(input.splice(0, howMany))
  }
  return result;
}

const separatedInGroups = spliceArrayInGroups(rowContents, 4);

const result = separatedInGroups.map(function(row, ri) {
  // here you iterate over your grouped items and form your cols.
  const cols = item.map((item, ci) => <Col key={ri+'-'+ci} id={item.id} className={"col-md-3 " + item.type}>{item.contents}</Col>)

  // then you wrap them into a row.
  return <Row key={${ri}}>${cols}<Row>
})
```