# Javascript data grouping and rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking to take an array - and then group it and render it. This is close to my production solution - but I've noticed a bug - where the data in the initial array - gets re-ordered if the split falls short.

-- so I would want to group the array into chunks of 4 --- label, value, label, value --- and if it falls short to just 2 items -- that seems to fall at the top of the getData output?

https://jsfiddle.net/2tv8d9bq/2/

```
let a = [{
    id: 'promotionTypeLabel',
    type: 'label',
    contents: "test",
  },
  {
    id: 'promotionTypeValue',
    type: 'value',
    contents: "test",
  },
  {
    id: 'promotionDiscountTypeLabel',
    type: 'label',
    contents: "test",
  },
  {
    id: 'promotionDiscountTypeValue',
    type: 'value',
    contents: "test",
  },
];

let b = [{
    id: 'regionForPromotionLabel',
    type: 'label',
    contents: "test",
  },
  {
    id: 'regionForPromotionValue',
    type: 'value',
    contents: "test",
  },
];

let c = [];
let showC = true;
if (showC) {
  c = [{
      id: 'fundingSourceLabel',
      type: 'label',
      contents: "test",
    },
    {
      id: 'fundingSourceValue',
      type: 'value',
      contents: "test"
    },
  ];
}

let d = [];
let showD = true;
if (showD) {
  d = [{
      id: 'discountPercentageLabel',
      type: 'label',
      contents: "test",
    },
    {
      id: 'discountPercentageValue',
      type: 'value',
      contents: "test",
    },

    {
      id: 'discountPercentageMinLabel',
      type: 'label',
      contents: "test",
    },
    {
      id: 'discountPercentageMinValue',
      type: 'value',
      contents: "test",
    },

    {
      id: 'discountItemLimitLabel',
      type: 'label',
      contents: "test",
    },
    {
      id: 'discountItemLimitValue',
      type: 'value',
      contents: "test",
    },
  ];
}

let e = [];
let showE = true;
if (showE) {
  e = [{
      id: 'quantityLabel',
      type: 'label',
      contents: "test",
    },
    {
      id: 'quantityValue',
      type: 'value',
      contents: "test"
    },
  ];
}

let f = [{
    id: 'deadlineDateLabel',
    type: 'label',
    contents: "test",
  },
  {
    id: 'deadlineDateValue',
    type: 'value',
    contents: "test",
  },
];

let rowContentsNotCollapsed = [...a, ...b, ...c, ...d, ...e, ...f];

console.log("rowContentsNotCollapsed", rowContentsNotCollapsed);



const getData = (r, splitBy) =>
  r
  .reduce(
    (s, a) => (
      s[0].push(a),
      s[0].length === splitBy ?
      (s.push(s[0]), (s[0] = [])) :
      s,
      s
    ),
    [
      []
    ],
  )
  .filter(a => a.length);



/*
let createRow = (item, i) => {
  return ( <
    Row className = "shell-detail-row" > {
      item.map(item => ( <
        Col key = {
          i
        }
        id = {
          item.id
        }
        className = {
          item.type +
          ' ' +
          (item.type == 'label' ? 'col-md-2' : 'col-md-4')
        } >
        {
          item.contents
        } <
        /Col>
      ))
    } <
    /Row>
  );
};
*/


getData(rowContentsNotCollapsed, 4).map((item, i) => {
  console.log("item", item);
  //return this.createRow(item, i);
})
```

Comment: please add which data you have for grouping and the wanted result (or add a comment, if already inserted).

Comment: this function -- works -- over the getData function - but why - function spliceArrayInGroups(list, howMany) {
  var result = []
  input = list.slice(0)
  while (input[0]) {
    result.push(input.splice(0, howMany))
  }
  return result;
}

const separatedInGroups = spliceArrayInGroups(rowContents, 4);

Comment: deadlineDateLabel  - should be at the bottom of the array --- but when it gets rendered - because its part of a group with just 2 items instead of 4 -- it gets rendered at the top --- but the spliceArrayInGroups function substitute doesn't have this error